# JS OOP outside prototype function call ( scope )

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I'm new to OOP, and I'm writing a simple game script to learn the OOP principles.

```
//main game function
battleLevel.prototype = 
{   

    battle:function () {      
        this.obj1 = {
          enterMonsterMenu: function() {
            return console.log('enterMonsterMenu');
          }
        };    
    },    

} /* end OOP prototype */



//external contructor
var Hero = function (warpX, warpY, game, name, life, mana, speed) {
  //some code
};

Hero.prototype.monsterSelectUp = function() {
    console.log('monsterSelectUp');
    //this.enterMonsterMenu();
    battleLevel.prototype.battle.call(obj1);
};
```

I want to access enterMonsterMenu() method by calling the monsterSelectUp() but I can't call it properly. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't get the concepts right, try to re-read at least [this short intro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Let's try to look what happens in the line where you are trying to call "enterMonsterMenu".
Here it is:

```
battleLevel.prototype.battle.call(obj1);
```

The `battleLevel.prototype` is an object you defined first.
The `battleLevel.prototype.battle` is a function and you execute it's "call" method (because functions are also objects in js and have functions like "call").

What does "function.call" [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)? It calls the function with given `this` value. 
For example,

```js
var myObject = { name: "Object 1" };
var yourObject = { name: "Object 2" };

function test() {
    alert(this.name);
}

test.call(myObject); //alert Object 1
test.call(yourObject); //alert Object 2
```

In your code, you are trying to call the `battleLevel.prototype.battle` and passing the `obj1` as `this`.

But at that point of code there is no `obj1` variable defined, so you just call the `battle` method with undefined variable.

Moreover, even if you passed the defined variable, you would not call the `enterMonsterMenu` function anyway. Because your method only adds the `obj1` property to the `this` object:

```js
battleLevel = {}
battleLevel.prototype = 
{   

    battle:function () {      
        this.obj1 = {
          enterMonsterMenu: function() {
            alert('enterMonsterMenu');
          }
        };    
    },    

}


var myThis = {"property": "value"};
alert(JSON.stringify(myThis)); // {"property": "value"};
// This call will add "obj1" property to myThis
battleLevel.prototype.battle.call(myThis);
alert(JSON.stringify(myThis)); // {"property": "value", "obj1": {}};
// now call the 'enterMonsterMenu'
myThis.obj1.enterMonsterMenu();
```

You can see above how you can actually call your `enterMonsterMenu`, but to be honest, I see no point in doing things like this. And, as I said, you probably need to spend more time on learning the concepts.

Comment: thank for your reply :), I am trying to solve here the scope problem.

I don't know if it's even possible to call any method which are inside battleLevel.prototype from inside another prototype method ?

Comment: @PawełKwiatkowski you should not call the methods from prototypes at all. Instead you need to create regular objects and used them. For example, `level = new BattleLevel(); hero = new Hero(); hero.enterLevel(level)` and inside the `enterLevel` you can call level methods `level.doSomethingWithHero(this)`.

Comment: @PawełKwiatkowski also I don't see the point in creating the new object inside the `battle` method and assigning it to `this`. What are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of the "obj1"?

Comment: I was trying to find any way to call method inside prototype, it doesn't mean anything. The previous version was like this, and I can't reach it:


battleLevel.prototype = 
{   
this.enterMonsterMenu: function() {
     alert('enterMonsterMenu');
}
}

Comment: @PawełKwiatkowski are you trying to define the 'enterMonsterMenu' as a method of the battleLevel.prototype? If should look this way then: `battleLevel.prototype = { enterMonsterMenu: function() {alert('enter'); } }` and you can call it as `battleLevel.prototype.enterMonsterMenu()`. I am still not sure if you really need the prototype. If you only have one battle level object, just do `battleLevel = { enterMonsterMenu: function() {alert('enter'); } }` and then `battleLevel.enterMonsterMenue()`.